# What is the purpose of this circuit from an ATX power supply?

Tags: power-supply, transistors, schematics, atx

I am trying to understand the working of this circuit but I didn't get the exact intuition.

The circuit is extracted from an ATX power supply. The objective is to have 5V and 3V3 (and of course others not mentioned here.) From the circuit the 5V and 3V3 are the input voltages and the output voltage is **1IN-** which is then fed into a feedback cicuit to adjust the error on the 5V and 3V3.

My questions are:

1. Is this a familiar transistor construction that has a name?
2. If not, how can I interpret the information given in 1IN- voltage?
3. What are the the capacitors used for here?

[image]

NB : I am newbie so don't assume the circuit is correct 100%. (I have a doubt about Q4 base and I can't re-check it.)

Comment: `i didn't get the exact intuition` ... that is difficult with a convoluted schematic diagram ... redraw the circuit so that it is horizontal with 5 V is on left, 3.3 V is on right ... basically, going from left to right, 5 V, R17, Q3, R21, Q4, 3.3 V ... redraw the rest of the components to match

Comment: Doesn't even look to me as though \$Q_4\$ can be active or saturated until the \$3V3\$ line goes below about half, or \$1.6\:\text{V}\$. So that doesn't sound like "adjust the error" to me. It looks more like a "detection" circuit. Does \$1IN-\$ sink? What's it hooked to? (Not in general; I mean more specifically than that.)

Comment: the 1IN- is hooked into an IC called TL494. Why do you think it is a detection cicuit ?

Comment: I simulated your 'extracted' circuit, but it doesn't make much sense because the switch-over point with 5V rail at 5V is ~1.7V on the 3.3V rail. Can you show us more of the circuit?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Unfortunately, the rest it's not easy for me to extract and putting the whole will complicate the question. But there is a bunch of schematics on the internet of ATX power supply which are based on TL494   and they are basically the same

Comment: I looked at a bunch of ATX circuits on the 'net and didn't see anything like yours. Can you link to an example?

Comment: Did you look at amplifiers  input of the TL494 circuit ??  i wouldn't trace it if i found something exactly similar. thank you anyway, i will get with the explanation given by @Jay for now until i get a ckearer question to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Q4 switches Q3 on, when [5V] [AND] [3V3] are established (with some conditions). And then, 1IN- sees current, thus voltage, through D7. D7 is a reverse blocking diode.

If Q3 & Q4 are not in switching mode, 1IN- reflects [5V - 3V3]. This case, 5V is likely static, and the 1IN- is current (to voltage on R). Thus 3V3 can be monitored/controlled. Depending on nodes of static/dynamic operations, Q3 & Q4 are arranged to work in Common-Emitter and/or Comm-Base.

Comment: could you develop a little bit the "(with some condition)"  please ?

Comment: in the second paragraph i am pretty sure 5V is not static and yes, both voltages are monitored /controlled

Comment: @miraclegenuis The "conditions" that may place Q4 and/or Q3 in saturation and/or active-region, and the setup timing of 5V & 3V3. I cannot tell better, since the resistor values are off from reasonable and the circuit is incomplete. Either case, of what I answered, 1IN- is the "difference" of 5V & 3V, could be binary (is or not), or could be proportional. Aha, you had one more question about the caps. All caps are low-pass / noise prevention / delay / stabilization, depends on how you look at, depends on what the entire circuitry is.

Comment: I think, i need to give you more information to allow you give me precise answer, But your point about that this circuit is probably only for monitoring/controlling  3V3 rail is more admissible assuming that the 5V is  controlled/monitored somewhere somehow.
in other side, the proportionality  you talk about is what i was looking for at first. Anyway, thank you Jay there is  some information in your answer.